# Change findByCriteria query using session factory

Tags: spring, hibernate

Can any one help me convert the `hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria` query using org.hibernate.Session

```
hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria.forClass(ALModel.class), alTotalCount, 40);
```

What this query does is the next question.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuuming `session` is of type `org.hibernate.Session`:

```
session.createCriteria(ALModel.class)
    .setFirstResult(alTotalCount)
    .setMaxResults(40)
```

The `hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria, int, int)` is used to create pagination queries similar to the converted criteria above.